# How to automatically launch Pycharm debug command line every time?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 5.0 now and every time I debug my program, I have to click Tools-->Open debug command line to open the interactive mode at the console. I was wondering if there is a default setting which can automatically open the interactive mode every time when debugging.